# how do I retain search form results while submitting another form on the page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I start by showing a list of businesses I have stored in a db. There is a form to search by industry or state. When showing a list of search results, I also provide the option to move the businesses to different tables. After submitting the form to move a business to a different table, the list refreshes to default result list, and we have to enter search term again.

I've tried assigning $_POST values  to dynamic urls in the action url of my forms, I've tried assigning $_POST values to the value="" parameter of my forms.

```
<?php

if  (isset($_POST['update']) && ($_POST['update'] == 'true')){ 
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO table1 (columns,columns,columns)
               SELECT columns,columns,columns
               FROM table2 WHERE id = 1';

               if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {} 
} 

?>

<div>
<form action="./?action=list" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="true" />
<input placeholder=" INDUSTRY" type="text" size="15" name="kw" />
<select name="state" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option value=''>BY STATE</option>
<?php require('includes/stateselect.php'); ?>
</select>&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
</div>

    <table>
    <?php
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM db.table ';

    if ((isset($_POST['kw'])) && (!empty($_POST['kw']))){
        $sql .=' WHERE `kw` LIKE \'%'.$_REQUEST['kw'].'%\'  OR  `biz` LIKE \'%'.$_POST['kw'].'%\' ';
        }

    if ((isset($_POST['state'])) && (!empty($_POST['state']))){  
        $sql .=' WHERE `state` = \''.$_POST['state'].'\' ';
        }

        if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo '<tr><form method="POST" action="./?action=list">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="update" value="true" />

            <td>'.$row['kw'] .'</td><td>'. $row['state'].'</td>';

            echo '<td>
                 <select name="move">
                    <option>--Fresh--</option>
                    <option value="dnc">DNC</option>
                 </select>';

            echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
            echo '</td></form></tr>';   

            }
        }

?>

</table>
```

We want to be able to search for lawyers, then disposition them from the list as we call them, but retain our search results.

Comment: FYI, you are creating invalid HTML - you can not nest a form between TR and TD elements like that. It needs to either go around the whole table, or be contained in a single table cell. You should fix this, otherwise automatic error correction by browsers might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @04FS Thank you. This is for a web based CRM used onsite, in Chrome only. I have moved the entire form into a single cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the search term inside a session so that you can use that term multiple times in your form. Store the search term in the session like this,

```
if ((isset($_POST['kw'])) && (!empty($_POST['kw']))){\
    $_SESSION['search_term] = $_POST['kw'];
    $sql .=' WHERE `kw` LIKE \'%'.$_REQUEST['kw'].'%\'  OR  `biz` LIKE 
         \'%'.$_POST['kw'].'%\' ';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to re-set the `kw` as a hidden input within the second form to retain the search terms, like this :

```
<?php

if  (isset($_POST['update']) && ($_POST['update'] == 'true')){ 
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO table1 (columns,columns,columns)
            SELECT columns,columns,columns
            FROM table2 WHERE id = 1';

            if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {} 
} 

?>

<div>
    <form action="./?action=list" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="search" value="true" />
        <input placeholder=" INDUSTRY" type="text" size="15" name="kw" />
        <select name="state" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
        <option value=''>BY STATE</option>
        <?php require('includes/stateselect.php'); ?>
        </select>&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="SEARCH">
    </form>
</div>

    <table>
    <?php
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM db.table ';

    if ((isset($_POST['kw'])) && (!empty($_POST['kw']))){
        $sql .=' WHERE `kw` LIKE \'%'.$_REQUEST['kw'].'%\'  OR  `biz` LIKE \'%'.$_POST['kw'].'%\' ';
        }

    if ((isset($_POST['state'])) && (!empty($_POST['state']))){  
        $sql .=' WHERE `state` = \''.$_POST['state'].'\' ';
        }

        if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo '<tr><form method="POST" action="./?action=list">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="update" value="true" />

            <td>'.$row['kw'] .'</td><td>'. $row['state'].'</td>';

            echo '<td>
                <select name="move">
                    <option>--Fresh--</option>
                    <option value="dnc">DNC</option>
                </select>';

            // added below blocks
            if (!empty($_POST['kw'])){
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="kw" value="'.$_POST['kw'].'" />';
                // echo '<input type="hidden" name="search" value="true" />';
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['state'])){
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="state" value="'.$_POST['state'].'" />';
            }
            echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
            echo '</td></form></tr>';   

            }
        }

?>

</table>
```

Comment: how come when I add the following right below the code you provided:

`echo '<input type="hidden" name="state" value="'.$_POST['state'].'" />';`

it doesn't work to retain the state info?

Comment: Hi @DavidWatson, I'm pretty certain that if the `$_POST['state']` is being sent on the first form, then the code you provide will also retain the state data on the second form. Could you debug it on the second form by : `print_r($_POST['state']);die();`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `$_POST['state']`